# i want to fetch selected batch's students data in table usig jquery and ajax in laravel 10 but the student data is not fetched

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

## This is the code of form and blade view

```
<form method="POST" action={{ route('markAttendence') }}>
                            @csrf

   <select class="form-control mb-4" name="stu_name" id="batch-select">
   </select>
   <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-label" for="datepicker">Select Date:</label>
      <input class="form-control _ge_de_ol" name="DOA" type="text" id="datepicker">
   </div>

   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Picture</th>
            <th scope="col">Cnic</th>
            <th scope="col">Attendence</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>

       </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
       <button 
         type="submit" 
         name="submit" 
         class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg"
       >
         Mark Attendance
       </button>
    </div>
                            
                            
 </div>
    
 </form>
```

## This is the routes

```
Route::get('/fetch/batchs',[attendanceController::class,'fetchBatches'])->name('fetchBatches');
Route::get('/fetch/students',[attendanceController::class,'fetchStudents'])->name('fetchStudents');
```

## This is the controller code

```
public function fetchBatches()
{
    $batches = batch::all(); // Assuming you have a Batch model
    return response()->json($batches);
}

public function fetchStudents(Request $request)
{
    $batchId = $request->input('batch_id');
    $students = students::where('Batch_id', $batchId)->get(); // Assuming you have a Student model
    return response()->json($students);

}
```

**
where I am making a mistake the data is not being fetched and I also got this error
**
**GET http://localhost:8000/fetch/students?batch_id=15 500 (Internal Server Error)**

I want to select any batch and the all students of that batch fetched in the table so that I can mark there attendance.

Comment: Did you check your log why error 500 is happening? error 500 is too broad of an error message

Comment: <form method="POST" action={{ route('markAttendence') }}>, where you define this route?where is your view page?